# Best practices to Initialize and populate a serverless PostgreSQL RDS instance by a CloudFormation stack deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, pg-restore

We are successfully spinning up an AWS CloudFormation stack that includes a serverless RDS PostgreSQL instance. Once the PostgreSQL instance is in place, we're automatically restoring a PostgreSQL database dump (in binary format) that was created using pg_dump on a local development machine on the instance PostgreSQL instance just created by CloudFormation.

We're using a Lambda function (instantiated by the CloudFormation process) that includes a build of the pg_restore executable within a Lambda layer and we've also packaged our database dump file within the Lambda.

The above approached seems complicated for something that presumably has been solved many times... but Google searches have revealed almost nothing that corresponds to our scenario. ​We may be thinking about our situation in the wrong way, so please feel free to offer a different approach (e.g., is there a CodePipeline/CodeBuild approach that would automate everything). Our preference would be to stick with the AWS toolset as much as possible.

This process will be run every time we deploy to a new environment (e.g., development, test, stage, pre-production, demonstration, alpha, beta, production, troubleshooting) potentially per release as part of our CI/CD practices.

Does anyone have advice or a blog post that illustrates another way to achieve our goal?

Answer (score 0):

If you have provisioned everything via IaC (Infrastructure as Code) anyway that is most of the time-saving done and you should already be able to replicate your infrastructure to other accounts/ stacks via different roles in your AWS credentials and config files by passing the —profile some-profile flag. I would recommend AWS SAM (Serverless application model) over Cloudformation though as I find I only need to write ~1/2 the code (roles & policies are created for you mostly) and much better & faster feedback via the console. I would also recommend sam sync (it is in beta currently but worth using) so you don’t need to create a ‘change set’ on code updates, purely the code is updated so deploys take 3-4 secs. Some AWS SAM examples here, check both videos and patterns: https://serverlessland.com (official AWS site)

In terms of the restore of RDS, I’d probably create a base RDS then take a snapshot of that and restore all other RDS instances from snapshots rather than manually creating it all the time you are able to copy snapshots and in fact automate backups to snapshots cross-account (and cross-region if required) which should be a little cleaner

There is also a clean solution for replicating data instantaneously across AWS Accounts using AWS DMS (Data Migration Services) and CDC (Change Data Capture). So, process is you have a source DB and a target DB and also a 'Replication Instance' (eg EC2 Micro) that monitors your source DB and can replicate that across to different instances (so you are always in sync on data, for example if you have several devs working on separate 'stacks' to not pollute each others' logs, you can replicate data and changes out seamlessly if required from one DB) - so this works with Source DB and Destination DB both already in AWS however you can also use AWS DMS of course for local DB migration over to AWS, some more  info here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sbs/chap-manageddatabases.html

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions - I like the idea of using database snapshots to move between environments, but we're running into complexity trying to develop remotely and upload database content and other DDL changes to our development environment - would you have any advice regarding our development approach for the database?

Comment: @Neoheurist updated answer on AWS DMS & CDC thanks